# Blank search does not return error in Django

Tags: python, django

I need some help with a problem i am facing, where I cannot seem to figure out the problem. Basically, I have a search function that is supposed to return an a message 'nothing entered!' if the entry is blank. However, it does not work.

fyi this is an example from the book masteringDjango - similar, but not 100% identical. My code below:

**search function**:

```
def search(request):
    if 'title' in request.GET:
        message = 'You searched for: %r' % request.GET['title']
    else:
        message = 'nothing entered!'
    return HttpResponse(message)
```

**search form**:

```
<form class="form-inline pull-xs-left" role="search" method="GET" action="/search/">
    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="title" placeholder="Search">
    <button class="btn btn-success-outline" type="submit">Search</button>
  </form>
```

**urls.py**:

```
urlpatterns = [
...
url(r'^search/$', views.search, name='search'),
]
```

Do let me know if more information is needed. Am still learning every step of the way, many thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried setting a breakpoint or looking what is in the get?

Comment: yes i have and my input does go into the get. if it is blank title = '', and it still passes through normally..the suggestion by Maxime B below works. Thanks Sayse!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your input is of type `text`, the `title` input is always sent, even if empty. Therefore, your view receive the content like this :

```
request.GET['title'] = ''
```

You have to check the content of the input, here's a bit of code :

```
def search(request):
    if 'title' in request.GET and request.GET['title']:
        message = 'You searched for: %r' % request.GET['title']
    else:
        message = 'nothing entered!'
    return HttpResponse(message)
```

Comment: I think you don't want the `not` in front of `request.GET['title']`

Comment: Wow sorry, got a boolean confusion :D